# how to get table row checkbox selected data to post route using expressjs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

how to get a dynamic table selected checkbox values and each row value to post route

```
app.post("/", (req, res)=>{

//get the values of each tbl row value here;

var val1 = req.body.test1; // 1

var val2 = req.body.test1; // 2

var val3 = req.body.test1; // 3
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVM3u.png)

Comment: Correct your question because it is incomprehensible. And add more code, because it seems to me that there is no data here that I should refer to

Answer (score 0):

You should complete the details to your question. Provide the data and functions that would connect the dots. So that we will be able to help you with your problem.